# CSS disabled horizontal scrolling working on local server, but not on domain

Tags: html, css, scroll, server, live

```
html, body {
max-width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This is the code I have added to my CSS. This works great and doesn't allow horizontal scrolling (including clicking and dragging of elements to scroll). However, for some reason even though I can see the code when published on my domain through dev tools, I can still click and scroll.

This isn't a problem on a desktop, but on my IPhone for example it creates a small white line along the right side of the screen which is very annoying.

I was wondering if anybody could help me with this problem, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
* {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Also remove this style, from your website

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave it a try, but I am still stuck with the same issue. Adding     overflow-y: hidden; disabled vertical scrolling.

Comment: @ThomasStockton yeah, but you say, you have a scrollbar in the right, so I decided you need this one

Comment: Oh no that wasn't the issue. I just meant there is a blank white space along the right due to the slight horizontal scrolling.

Comment: The problem still occurs unfortunately. Thought that would really fix it too. Just can't figure out why it works locally and not on the domain.

Comment: @ThomasStockton Are you test in iPhone localy?

Comment: No, the IPhone test is through the domain. However, when I test on the domain on my desktop I can also see the slight horizontal scroll.

Comment: What browser are you use? Can you add screenshot?

Comment: Apparently I don't have a high enough reputation to provide an image, but I can post the domain and you can see for yourself. http://jamesvickersdrums.com/

Comment: @nishanths This is my current viewport.    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @ThomasStockton i found it! remove `.margin-right: -15px;` from .row class!

Comment: @ThomasStockton I'm updated the answer, please do everything like on it!

Comment: It worked! That was really frustrating for me, was starting to think I wouldn't be able to find a solution. I honestly can't take you enough.

Comment: @ThomasStockton nice!